# How to get WindowCount of other applications using Swift

Tags: swift, macos, window

how do I get the current `WindowCount` of other applications?
I'm using `Swift` as programming language and developing for OS X.

Have a nice day.

Answer (score 1):

Import `CoreGraphics` and check out `CGWindowListCopyWindowInfo`:

```
import CoreGraphics

let kCGNullWindowID: UInt32 = 0

// Check the documentation for other options
guard let windows = CGWindowListCopyWindowInfo([.OptionOnScreenOnly], kCGNullWindowID) as NSArray? as? [[String: AnyObject]] else {
    fatalError("Can't find windows")
}

var windowCount = [String: Int]()
windows.forEach {
    let ownerName = $0[kCGWindowOwnerName as String] as! String
    if let count = windowCount[ownerName] {
        windowCount[ownerName] = count + 1
    } else {
        windowCount[ownerName] = 1
    }
}

print(windowCount)
```

Comment: Doesn't work correctly, result is `["Xcode": 1, "Dock": 2, "Safari": 1, "Finder": 1, "SystemUIServer": 2, "Spotlight": 1, "Window Server": 2]`, but the background processes like `Dock`, `SystemUIServer`, `Spotlight` and `Window Server` do not have any window. And for testing I closed the Finder window, but its count is also declared as `1`.